# A isomorphism between C*-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $J\triangleleft A$ be an ideal, then $A^{**}\cong J^{**}\oplus(A/J)^{**}$ ? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key concept here is that of *annihilator*. For a subset $X\subset A$, the annihilator of $X$ is the subset of $A^*$ given by
$$
X^o=\{f\in A^*: f(x)=0\,\forall x\in X\}.
$$
*(note that almost all equal signs below mean isomorphism)*

It is not hard to prove that $X^{oo}=X^{**}$. Now if $A=X\oplus Y$, then $A^*=X^*\oplus Y^*$. Also $X=A/Y$, $Y=A/X$. And it is also not hard to check that $(A/X)^*= X^o$. Then
$$
A^*=X^*\oplus Y^*=(A/Y)^*\oplus (A/X)^*=Y^o\oplus X^o
$$
Then, as $A=J\oplus (A/J)$,
$$
A^{**}=J^{oo}\oplus (A/J)^{oo}=J^{**}\oplus (A/J)^{**}.
$$

Comment: 1. Does $X^{oo}=X^{**}$ hold? Why ? 2. if $A=X\oplus Y$, then $A^{*}=X^{*}\oplus Y^{*}$??

Comment: 1. For any $x\in X$ and $f\in X^o$, $xf=f(x)=0$. As $X$ is weak-$*$ dense in $X^{**} $, $\alpha f=0$ for all $\alpha$ in   $X^{**}$. So $X^{**}\subset X^{oo} $.

Comment: 2. You can map $f\in A^*$ to $(f|_X,f|_Y)\in X^*\oplus Y^*$. This is linear, one-to-one, and onto.

Comment: So, the equal sign of $X^{**}=X^{oo}$ means equality, not isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, you are right.